# ¿Cómo generar divs mediante un array de objetos? jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, bucles, clausuras

Lo que quiero es que se recorra el array de objetos `material` y genere un `div` por cada elemento y que en el primer div ponga `elemento1`, en el segundo `elemento2`, etc.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
var material = [{nombre: 'elemento1'},{nombre: 'elemento2'},{nombre: 'elemento3'}]

var longitud = material.length; i=0;

for(i; i<longitud; i++){
    $("#lista-material").append(
        ' <a href="#"><div class="item col-xs-6 col-ms-3 col-md-3 col-xl-3"></div></a>'
    );                  
    $(".item").html(material[i].nombre);
};
```

El resultado que espero es:

```
div1.innerHTML = elemento1
div2.innerHTML = elemento2
div3.innerHTML = elemento3
```

El resultado que obtengo es:

```
div1.innerHTML = elemento3
div2.innerHTML = elemento3
div3.innerHTML = elemento3
```

<sub>**Aclaraciones de codigo:** `#lista-material` es un contenedor donde están todos *divs* generados.</sub>

Comment: Hola Pablo bienvenido. Como recomendacion, usa " ` " (backtick) para los nombre de variables en vez de negrita. Un saludo!

Comment: En [este fiddle que hice](https://jsfiddle.net/tpo3rytn/1/)  con tu codigo, funciona bien.

Comment: ¿Con qué finalidad se quiere lograr esto? Llegado el caso, tampoco sería necesario crear el array `material`, ya que los números `1`, `2` y demás, se generarían automáticamente desde un `for`.

Comment: @ArtEze esto es de cuando estaba aprendiendo a programar, así que no te lo tomes muy enserio :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en la siguiente línea de código:

```
$(".item").html(material[i].nombre);
```

Este código **selecciona todos los `div`** de clase `.item` previamente generados y los establece al último valor del array.

Aquí tienes un [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tpo3rytn/3/) dónde se reproduce el error.

**Solución:**

Para solventarlo puedes, por ejemplo, ponerle como `id` el nombre del elemento y seleccionar ese `id` en vez de la clase `.item`:

```js
var material = [{nombre: 'elemento1'},{nombre: 'elemento2'},{nombre: 'elemento3'}]

var longitud = material.length;

for(var i=0; i<longitud; i++){
  console.log(material[i].nombre);
  $("#lista-material").append(
    ' <a href="#"><div id="'
    + material[i].nombre
    + '" class="item col-xs-6 col-ms-3 col-md-3 col-xl-3"></div></a>'
  );                   
  $('#' + material[i].nombre).html(material[i].nombre);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lista-material" />
```